# How do you (currently) change app's general theme and look and feel using Onsen-UI? (not just colors)

Tags: onsen-ui

I recently startet to develop using OnsenUI, and found some very good docs. However, I think with the last update, some of it got obsolete, more specifically the theme-related one.

http://onsenui.io/blog/cutomize-onsenui-theme/

I found the post above, which shows how to chage specific aspects of a theme, and from there, we can assume how to change the general theme and look and feel of an app (android, iOS, etc). However, none of the stated there seems to work anymore, since now there isn't a "themes" folder. I think it's because of the recent implementation they did with the "Onsen CSS Components"

So, my specific question is: Is there a way (now, with the latest version) to change the general theme and look and feel similary to the stated on that post? Or by now, is this (http://components.onsenui.io/, which only lets you change the colors, or manually modify CSS) the only way of customization?

Any help would be very much appreciated, since I'm finding Onsen-UI as a very good choice to  mobile web developing, and I'm really wanting to use it, it's just that little problem is holding me back.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, we cannot customize the theme using the grunt server as shown in this [link](http://onsenui.io/blog/cutomize-onsenui-theme/) anymore. It is deprecated. In order to customize the theme, you can either:

1. editing the files: onsenui.css and onsen-css-components.css or
2. using the [OnsenUI components](http://components.onsenui.io/) to get specific theme you want and click the "Download Theme" button. This will change the look and feel of the whole app. However, if you wanna customize a specific component, from the same link please go to "Patterns" > "Find Component". Then, click on the specific component you want. A window containing CSS specific for that component will popup. Then, you can copy and paste it into ur CSS file.

I hope it helps. If that's not answering your question, please let me know.